# Pydev can't import poplib

Tags: pydev, poplib

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 beta which comes with Pydev, everything appears to be working apart from I can't import poplib which is part of the standard library.

I added poplib to the Forced Builtins and it seems to prevent it marking it as an error but completions don't work. Am I doing this right? Shouldn't everything in the standard library just work?

Edit: I have the same problem with random as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I switched to the default system interpreter the problem went away, the virtualenv I was using must have been corrupt somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. But I'm using vanilla Eclipse, not Aptana. A good idea for all PyDev-related problems is to use the latest version as PyDev is under heavy development. Just enter "http://pydev.org/nightly" as update site and see whether there's a newer version.

Another idea is to re-parse the standard library: In the settings, choose the Python interpreter from the list and click "Apply". That should make PyDev parse the libraries again. You could also remove the interpreter and add it again.